# Unzipping an artifact with SBT

Tags: sbt

As part of my project build, I'd like to unzip a zip artifact of a managed dependency into a specific directory of the project. Before starting to use SBT I was doing this via an ANT script that would fetch the zip artifact from a maven dependency and unzip it.

My question(s) are:

- how to specify that I want to depend on the zip dependency? I have defined it like so:
  `"eu.delving"                %  "sip-creator"                     % "0.4.6-SNAPSHOT"`
  but this doesn't fetch the zip artifact
- where / how to hook into the build process to run the unzip (and how to refer to the artifact file in that context)?

Comment: Not yet. So far I'm still using the ANT version of it to do so

Comment: For the second part regarding hooking the unzipping action you should check the Tasks wiki https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks. Look up how to declare them and then establishing dependencies so that it triggers when building or packaging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to extract a set of managed dependencies, the code below should work. I tested it in sbt 0.12.0, but it should also work with 0.11.x.

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._
import Classpaths.managedJars

object TestBuild extends Build {

    lazy val jarsToExtract = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("jars-to-extract", "JAR files to be extracted")

    lazy val extractJarsTarget = SettingKey[File]("extract-jars-target", "Target directory for extracted JAR files")

    lazy val extractJars = TaskKey[Unit]("extract-jars", "Extracts JAR files")

    lazy val testSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
        // define dependencies
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
            "com.newrelic" % "newrelic-api" % "2.2.1"
        ),

        // collect jar files to be extracted from managed jar dependencies
        jarsToExtract <<= (classpathTypes, update) map { (ct, up) =>
            managedJars(Compile, ct, up) map { _.data } filter { _.getName.startsWith("newrelic-api") }
        },

        // define the target directory
        extractJarsTarget <<= (baseDirectory)(_ / "extracted"),

        // task to extract jar files
        extractJars <<= (jarsToExtract, extractJarsTarget, streams) map { (jars, target, streams) =>
            jars foreach { jar =>
                streams.log.info("Extracting " + jar.getName + " to " + target)
                IO.unzip(jar, target)
            }
        },

        // make it run before compile
        compile in Compile <<= extractJars map { _ => sbt.inc.Analysis.Empty }
    )

    lazy val test: Project = Project("test", file(".")) settings (testSettings: _*)
}
```

If you simply have jar files to extract, you can add them as unmanaged dependencies, ie. putting them into the /lib folder. See: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Library-Dependencies

If you really have zip files (or want to extract the unmanaged dependencies), you can change the above code to list them:

```scala
// list jar files to be extracted
jarsToExtract <<= (baseDirectory) map { dir => Seq(dir / "lib" / "newrelic-api-2.2.1.zip") },
```

You should now be able to manually extract them from sbt and they should automatically be extracted before compile:

```
> clean
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 12, 2012 5:39:16 PM
> extract-jars
[info] Extracting newrelic-api-2.2.1.zip to /Users/balagez/Sites/test/extracted
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 12, 2012 5:39:22 PM
> compile
[info] Extracting newrelic-api-2.2.1.zip to /Users/balagez/Sites/test/extracted
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 12, 2012 5:39:24 PM
```

Now you can add a new task or extend the existing one which extracts the zip file from the extracted dependency. If you don't need the contents of the dependency, you can use the task-temporary-directory setting which gives you a temporary directory writable by sbt:

```scala
// define the target directory
extractJarsTarget <<= taskTemporaryDirectory,
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I really have a ZIP file which is produced as an artifact on a maven repository. I'll check in the next days how it can be retrieved by SBT and then use your code to do the work.